# How to create a bar chart for this code using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently in a project with some friends, trying to work out some winrates of LoL teams. I want to make a bar chart based on each teams' winrate, but I'm constantly running into "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars", and I can't seem to understand where I'm getting it wrong.

My question would be, how do I transform this into a matplotlib bar chart? I'm just getting started into Python and programming in general, so I understand I may have made a lot of mistakes here.

I tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10,4

# Include EU team when defined (between JDG and C9)
teams = ['GenG', 'T1', 'JD Gaming', 'Cloud9', 'Bilibili Gaming', 'G2 Esports', 'Golden Guardians', 'PSG Talon', 'GAM Esports', 'Detonation FocusMe', 'LOUD', 'Movistar R7']
teams_dict = {'GenG':0, 'T1':1, 'JD Gaming':2, 'EU(TBD)':3, 'Cloud9':4, 'Bilibili Gaming': 5, 'G2 Esports': 6, 'Golden Guardians':7, 'PSG Talon':8, 'GAM Esports':9, 'Detonation FocusMe':10, 'LOUD':11, 'Movistar R7':12}

# Winrates
GenG_WR = [0.70]
T1_WR = [0.75]
JDG_WR = [0.77]
# EU_WR = TBD
C9_WR = [0.80]
BLG_WR = [0.59]
G2_WR = [0.67]
GG_WR = [0.54]
PSG_WR = [0.77]
GAM_WR = [0.76]
DFM_WR = [0.82]
LLL_WR = [0.72]
MR7_WR = [0.58]
# Winrates Array (include EU team when defined)
Winrates = np.array([GenG_WR, T1_WR, JDG_WR, C9_WR, BLG_WR, G2_WR, GG_WR, PSG_WR, GAM_WR, DFM_WR, LLL_WR, MR7_WR])

plt.bar(teams, Winrates)
plt.xticks(len(teams), teams)
plt.ylabel('Winrate %')
plt.title('Winrates for the Split')

plt.show()
```

Resulting in the TypeError I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

##The index used in the plt.xticks() function is incorrect. It should be plt.xticks(np.arange(len(teams)), teams) to set the ticks at every integer position.
##The winrates of the EU team are not defined, and there is a missing team between JD Gaming and Cloud9.
##The plt.bar() function expects an array of values for each team, but the Winrates array is a 2D array with only one value for each team.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10,4

# Include EU team when defined (between JDG and C9)
teams = ['GenG', 'T1', 'JD Gaming', 'EU(TBD)', 'Cloud9', 'Bilibili Gaming', 'G2 Esports', 'Golden Guardians', 'PSG Talon', 'GAM Esports', 'Detonation FocusMe', 'LOUD', 'Movistar R7']

# Winrates
GenG_WR = [0.70]
T1_WR = [0.75]
JDG_WR = [0.77]
EU_WR = [] # empty list for now, to be filled when EU team is defined
C9_WR = [0.80]
BLG_WR = [0.59]
G2_WR = [0.67]
GG_WR = [0.54]
PSG_WR = [0.77]
GAM_WR = [0.76]
DFM_WR = [0.82]
LLL_WR = [0.72]
MR7_WR = [0.58]

# Winrates Array (include EU team when defined)
Winrates = [GenG_WR, T1_WR, JDG_WR, EU_WR, C9_WR, BLG_WR, G2_WR, GG_WR, PSG_WR, GAM_WR, DFM_WR, LLL_WR, MR7_WR]
Winrates = np.array([np.array(team_wr, dtype=np.float64) if team_wr else np.nan for team_wr in Winrates])

plt.bar(teams, Winrates.flatten())
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(teams)), teams)
plt.ylabel('Winrate %')
plt.title('Winrates for the Split')

plt.show()
```